# getting unathorized error while accessin basic authentication api in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get data from api (having basic authentication). I'm passing username and password but still I'm getting **unauthorized** error. How to resolve unauthorized error.api sending json data but I'm not able access it .

**Code:**

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{ x.name}}</td>
                <td>{{ x.city }}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('https://example.com/node1', {
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'user1:user1@123' }
      }).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the cors issue? - https://devblast.com/b/cors-with-angular-js-and-sinatra

Comment: What's the response are you getting ? Can you put a `console.log`  in the response function and share it.

Comment: i installed cors plugin for chrome. so it resolved for temporarily

Comment: You may want to try hashing the password before you send it. Technically no one can answer this question it can only be guessed at. The API documentation will tell you what you need to do. If you can provide a link to the API documentation we maybe able to work out the issue.

Comment: in the url while we hit the api , there we are giving username and password without encoding and getting result, then y in the ajax call its not working

Comment: api documentaion -
Messages are REST based following the “CRUD” principle with transport over HTTPS. Authentication is done using the Basic authentication scheme of HTTP(S). Basic authentication uses the standard header field “Authorization” with the argument string: “Basic [username:password]base64 encoded”. Data exchanged in the message body is JSON format and will have “Content-Type” HTTP header directives with “application/json”. All messages are HTTP v1.1 compliant..

Comment: according to your comment, you aren't following the API documentation.  It says you need to pass the `[username:password]` **base64 encoded**.  Has your question now changed to how to encode the password?

Comment: now unauthorized error resolved. but unable to see any data